# JSP POST not working

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat8

There is a simple JSP like this:

```
<%
    //some code here
%>
<html>
    <form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <!-- some fields here -->
    </form>
</html>
```

The code is being executed if the form is using GET and is being skipped if using POST.
Why?
PLEASE NOTE:
This question is NOT about servlets, forms and file uploading!
I am asking why the code is not executed when my JSP is called with a POST instead of a GET!

Comment: Are you using springMVC?

Comment: try to add the action attribute in the form with the according jsp file name

Comment: @MouadELFakir No frameworks

Comment: @simas_ch same problems